# How to measure VirtualizingStackPanel performance

Tags: c#, wpf, performance

I want to measure the VirtualizingStackPanel's performance. Following are the steps which i am using.

- Create 1000 items, without virtualization the UI will freeze which is really simple.
- I can use Snoop to show that it loads only items which are visible

Now i want to prove that when i scroll, it loads other few items only. Is there any event which i can use to prove this? Is there any other way to prove this?

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to prove this? Add new property to your structure, such as IsNotInMemory. You can add this to your ItemsTemplate:

```
                        <CheckBox x:Name="win" IsChecked="{Binding IsNotInMemory, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
                              Visibility="Collapsed"
                              >
```

You then can add another ListBox which has virtualizing disabled and it binds directly against IsNotInMemory. You then can see which items are currently in memory, and which ones are not. As you scroll in first listbox, you see that items are being loaded to memory one by one(EG TRUE goes false.)

Alternatively you can just hook yourself into Loaded&Unloaded event of DataTemplate. Note that if you use VirtualizingMode=Recycling, you possibly wont get any Unloaded event as they are being recycled. You can also hook yourself into DataContextChanged event on this case.